# Execute a one-way wcf service operation from powershell

Tags: .net, wcf, powershell

I have a scheduled task which executes a powershell script every hour.  The powershell script must make a call to a one-way WCF service operation.  Essentially it just needs to kick off an operation.  My question is how do I go about doing that?  I thought that just executing the url would in fact kick off the request but apparently that is not correct.

Here is what I was trying to do:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://myserver.com/myservice/dosomething")
$request.GetResponse()
```

The operation accepts no parameters and returns void.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PowerShell 2.0 makes this trivial with the New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet e.g.:

```
$zip = New-WebServiceProxy -uri http://www.webservicex.net/uszip.asmx?WSDL
$zip.getinfobyzip(20500).table

CITY      : Washington
STATE     : DC
ZIP       : 20500
AREA_CODE : 202
TIME_ZONE : E
```

Comment: If script gets called many times per day the reader might consider either compile the WS proxy in C#, or use fiddler to record the request and replay with much lighter-weight HTTP.

Answer (score 7):

I think the problem is that the code you have is actually creating an [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), not a WCF request. (In other words, it's simply executing an HTTP GET request on the URL, with no SOAP or .NET Remoting information.)

You should be able to follow these instructions to create a proper endpoint:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163647.aspx#S11

It should look something like this:

```
$httpBinding = New-Object System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding
$endpointAddress = New-Object System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress 'http://myserver.com/myservice/dosomething'
$contractDescription = [System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription]::GetContract([IYourInterface], $httpBinding, $endpointAddress)
$serviceEndpoint = New-Object System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint $contractDescription
$channelFactory = New-Object "System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory``1[IYourInterface]" $serviceEndpoint
$webProxy = $channelFactory.CreateChannel();
$webProxy.yourServiceMethod();
```

Note that you'll need to import the DLL with the `IYourInterface` class for this to work:

```
[void] [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('path/to/your.dll')
```

Alternatively, if you have a WSDL defined for the service, you can follow these much easier instructions to access the service:

http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/11/17/hey-scripting-guy-november-17-2009.aspx

Alternatively alternatively, you can figure out what the HTTP SOAP request needs to look like, and form it yourself within the `HttpWebRequest`.

Comment: Right.  I'm not looking to use SOAP.  Ideally I'd really like to simply execute get on a url in a rest-ful manner.  Is this possible with WCF?

Comment: WCF exposes services via SOAP. It also has a .NET-to-.NET binary backdoor built in, to eliminate the costs of the XML conversions.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation#Overview

Comment: The huge code sample is to use this backdoor to avoid the XML conversions. Using the SOAP interface is simply better supported in PowerShell, due to the built-in New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet.

Comment: It looks like they have an area devoted to hosting WCF over REST. From the looks of it, you will have to modify the service to expose a REST interface. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx

Comment: These options definitely look good.  I'm not concerned with performance.  I really just am looking for the easiest way to kick off a task via a wcf service via a scheduled task and would prefer not to have to create a new exe to do it (thus the powershell script).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @jdmichal: I have to say the link you provided (http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/archive/2009/11/17/hey-scripting-guy-november-17-2009.aspx) is amazing!  the WebServiceProxy class is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I like jdmichal's answer because it is intuitive to make it work for inputs where the parameters are objects... the code required some modifications, this is what worked for me:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\.....\WcfService2.dll")
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.ServiceModel")

$httpBinding = New-Object System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding
if($useNTLM){
    #passes the default creds
    $httpBinding.Security.Mode = "TransportCredentialOnly"
    $httpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = "Ntlm"
}
$endpointAddress = New-Object System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress 'http://localhost:63600/Service1.svc'

$contractDescription = [System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription]::GetContract([WcfService2.IService1])

$serviceEndpoint = New-Object System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint($contractDescription, $httpBinding, $endpointAddress)
$channelFactory = New-Object "System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory``1[WcfService2.IService1]"($serviceEndpoint)

$webProxy = $channelFactory.CreateChannel();
$result = $webProxy.GetData(123);
Write-Output $result #prints 123
$comptype = new-object WcfService2.CompositeType
$comptype.BoolValue =$false
$comptype.StringValue = "whatever123zxcv"
$result = $webProxy.GetDataUsingDataContract($comptype);
Write-Output $result #prints whatever123zxcv
```

UPDATE:
I've found out how to use composite objects with the New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet (thanks to http://www.sqlmusings.com/2012/02/04/resolving-ssrs-and-powershell-new-webserviceproxy-namespace-issue/)

```
$wsProxy = New-WebServiceProxy -uri http://localhost:63600/Service1.svc
$wsProxy.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$namespace = $wsProxy.GetType().Namespace
$myct = New-Object "$namespace.CompositeType"
$myct.BoolValue = $true;
$myct.StringValue = "asdfasdg";

$wsProxy.GetDataUsingDataContract($myct)
$wsProxy.GetData(123,$true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll need to set the HTTP method first before attempting to get a response. By default, I believe the **WebRequest** object defaults to **POST**, but you'll actually need to set it to **GET**.

I haven't used PowerShell scripting much, but based off of your sample it would look something like this:

```
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://myserver.com/myservice/dosomething") 
$request.Method = "GET"
$request.GetResponse()
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: In order to do this would I only have to expose the operation with a WebGet attribute and expose a RESTful endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP replay approach:

1. Install Fiddler, run it and start recording requests
2. invoke the WCF service using the 'normal' client (record the request)
3. use Invoke-WebRequest - replay the XML SOAP request body and some headers, be sure to match the headers: Content-Type, SOAPAction, and possibly others
4. repeat (3) and keep tweaking the body and headers until you have a valid SOAP request

You don't have to use WCF to call a WCF service, you can mimic one with 3-4 changes from HTTP defaults.  Just don't try to building the SOAP envelope yourself.  But it's safe to replay everything you need from Fiddler over 'plain' HTTP.