# Generic from other assembly

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I was trying to create WCF client following instructions from here:
[Execute a one-way wcf service operation from powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002954/execute-a-one-way-wcf-service-operation-from-powershell)

Here's the piece of code that is breaking

```
$contractDescription = [System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription]::GetContract([Iinterface])
$serviceEndpoint = New-Object System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint $contractDescription
$channelFactory = New-Object "System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory``1[Iinterface]" $serviceEndpoint
```

My interface is stored in a separate assembly that I have Add-Typed. What is puzzling me is that this

```
    $contractDescription = [System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription]::GetContract([Iinterface])
```

is working just fine, but

```
    $channelFactory = New-Object "System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory``1[Iinterface]" $serviceEndpoint
```

is failing with:

> New-Object : Cannot find type [System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1[Iinterface]]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
>   At C:\Users\amarchuk\AppData\Local\Temp\1\bbc2b1ab-fe3a-4982-a561-2bfe926b7362.ps1:29 char:29
>   + $channelFactory = New-Object <<<<  "System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory``1[Iinterface]" $serviceEndpoint
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Did I mess up syntax around generics?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to use

```
$channelFactory = New-Object 'System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory``1[System.Object]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$channelFactory = New-Object 'System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory``1'([Iinterface])
```

EDIT:

or

```
$channelFactory = New-Object -typename 'System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory``1'([Iinterface])
```

but i can test it.

Comment: This gives: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint'.